# SQL DataRetrival in VB.net Datatypes Error

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm Using SQL queries to get value from excelsheet to bind in datagridview but my problem is the excelsheet column contains different types of data then when i use sql query it only show specific data like long , double or string

Excelsheet column content

```
col1  col2
1     1209
2     1802
3     18nR
4     Uy61
5     1298
```

col1 loaded fine but in column 2 3rd and 4th cells shows empty I can't get what's the problem perhaps sql defining the column as integer Than Whats the possible solution Here(Actual column contains big data Here's table is an example to clearify question)

Comment: By default Excel Driver defines column type based on first 8 rows - so if first 8 cells are numbers - column becomes numeric and all non-numeric values are ignored. You may change that behavior by adjusting driver settings - Google "TypeGuessRows" and how it is used.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Thanks For Your reply, But can we do it w/o changing system or driver settings like Using some expressions in Query , Thanks

Comment: Because i'va changed it in registry but i'm still having problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
connection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 ;Data Source=" & Filepath & " ;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'")
```

Comment: Wow It's Great Buddy it's Working Exxcellent

Comment: Your Welcome  Jadeja RJ

Comment: Very cool. But keep in mind that Jet won't work on 64-bit systems and won't read Excel 2007 and above (XLSX) files. But I think similar approach should work for new driver as well.