# VB.NET Datagrid view not showing a complete column of Integer data

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

I am working on uploading a excel data to a datagrid view. The excel contains data about asset mapping (asset ID, EmpID1, EmpID2,  Project#, etc..,) for a particular project (*Some assets may be tagged to more than 1 associate, so I've 2 EmpId field & the second one may have null value)*. Here I am just trying to query (select *..) the excel & place it in a datatable (which I need for latter usage) & finally showing it in datagrid view. Though the data export happens fine, I am observing a peculiar behavior in vb.net

1) The EmpID2 column does not show any data (its fully blank), if there is no data within first 10 rows. i.e., if first 10 rows are blank for this column, then the entire column is blank in data grid view.

2) If at least one row has value (even if I manually add a junk digit) within first 10 rows, then I can see the data for rest of the rows are updated properly.

code snippet:

```
    Dim query_Assetsmapping As String = "select * from [sheet1$]"
    Dim MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=Asset_Mapping.xls; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0")
    Dim MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query_Assetsmapping, MyConnection)
    Dim DtSet = New System.Data.DataTable
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
    MyConnection.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.tables(0)
```

I don't see any datatype problem, coz I am just exporting the data from excel to data table without specifying or converting datatypes.

Help me in understanding, if anything needs to be explicitly specified for the datagrid view property, so I can show the entire data in the data grid.

Note: The EmpId field is a 6 digit number.

Comment: I think you are facing error of "TypeGuessRows" , By default Excel Driver defines column type based on first 8 rows - like if first 8 cells are numbers - column becomes numeric and all non-numeric values are ignored. So i suggest ou prefer this question  . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055324/sql-dataretrival-in-vb-net-datatypes-error

Comment: The Adapter fills a `DataSet` and the `DataSource` should be a `DataTable` = `DataGridView1.DataSource = YourDataSet.Tables(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your connection string

```
Dim MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=Asset_Mapping.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'")
```

Comment: Now I am stuck with another problem. Though the EmpID2 column is getting updated fine, I observe some users have updated there name along with the EmpID (which they are free to do so). So the field becomes non-numeric & Datagrid somehow considers the column to be numeric, and it does not populate any of the rows that has the string value in it. Though the solution provided above is supposed to clear this problem as well, I don't see it to be working by changing the connection string. Appreciate all your help in this regard..!!

Comment: Try Changing typeguess rows number of column in registry http://forums.asp.net/t/1578417.aspx

Comment: And if still problem occurs than you have to prevent users from entering non numeric values by providing ristriction to your data entering field

Comment: Now I've modified the source to have only numeric value. But now my second problem started when I am trying to find the assets that are tagged to invalid users (i.e., associates who're no longer in the project).

Comment: cont.. I've another excel source where I have the EmpId of all assocites who're in the company. Now I need to query the EmpID from 1st excel (asset mapping) & need to check whether it exists in 2nd excel (associate detail). If not, I need to have it updated in the datatable. Now when I check for EmpID1, its working perfectly fine (coz it is not nullable). But when I try to do the same with EmpID2 column & if there is no data in the first 10 rows, then it triggers a exception, "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E07): Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Comment: cont.. 'select [Asset ID], [EmpNo1] from [AssetMapping$] Where [EmpNo1] Not IN (SELECT [EmpID] FROM [EmployeeDetails$] IN "C:\Data\SecondWorkbook.xls" "EXCEL 8.0;")' --> Is working perfectly fine.

'select [Asset ID], [EmpNo2] from [AssetMapping$] Where [EmpNo2] Not IN (SELECT [EmpID] FROM [EmployeeDetails$] IN "C:\Data\SecondWorkbook.xls" "EXCEL 8.0;")' --> throws Exception

Plz assist me to get rid of this problem or let me know if any work around exists.